# Facebook Graph API iOS - only get public events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently getting user events in the following way:

```
 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"events.since(now)"....
```

I need one more specific detail: I only want the user's public event, not his private events. When querying the Graph API, I can add: me/events?fields=type and this allows me to see the type (private or public) of each event. But I can't find a way to add this parameter in my `FBSDKGraphRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is the following. Change the parameters to this:

```
events.since(now).fields(type)
```

This will display the "type" field in the resulting data. I was then able to filter and use only the public events!